# How to handle tags and segments in phonegap

Tags: phonegap-plugins, onesignal

Im making a dashboard for my users (in app) where they can subscribe to different segments, and would just check if I understood this somewhat right.

I make segments in onesignal.com dashboard, and in one segment i make a key = "value" (e.g test)

I send a push from my server and include

"tag" => "test",

Application can now use sendTag in an event (like a button user presses), and "subscribe" to that tag in app.

Is it more or less how this system works. I really have a hard time reading it out of the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this all correct, if you choose you can also use the `tags` field on the OneSignal [create notification](http://documentation.onesignal.com/v2.0/docs/notifications-create-notification) REST API POST call instead creating segments on the dashboard first.